# Suppress FindBugs warning with findFragmentByTag

Tags: android, casting, findbugs

I would like to suppress a FindBugs warning seen casting a `Fragment` obtained with `findFragmentByTag(String)`. This is the current code:

```
<Match>
    <Method name="findFragmentByTag" params="java.lang.String"
            returns="android.support.v4.app.Fragment"/>
    <Bug pattern="BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST_OF_RETURN_VALUE"/>
</Match>
```

I am following http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html) but it is not really work. Did anyone experience this problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that what you want to do will not work. What you're asking is for findbugs to ignore errors inside the the source code of   `Fragment.findFragmentByTag()` but your project most likely doesn't have that source code. Furthermore, i doubt that `findFragmentByTag` violates that rule.

What you need is to instruct findbugs to ignore **your** method that is calling `Fragment.findFragmentByTag()`.